# Numeric literal operator error

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

Why does this code:

```
constexpr float operator "" _deg(long double d) {
    // returns radians
    return d*3.1415926535/180;
}

static const float ANGLES[] = {-20_deg, -10_deg, 0_deg, 10_deg, 20_deg};
```

Produce 5 of these errors:

> error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator"" _deg'

I am using GCC 4.7.3. (`arm-none-eabi-g++`, with the `-std=c++0x` flag).

Comment: What compiler and version of it are you using?

Comment: But it fails on [ideone](http://ideone.com/9pZNTA) too

Comment: What _version_ of the compiler? [User defined literals is not properly implemented until gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). ideone is using gcc 4.5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems GCC doesn't do type conversions with user-defined literals, so e.g. the `-10` in `-10_deg` is considered to be an integer.

Add `.0` to all numbers and it should hopefully work:

```
static const float ANGLES[] = {-20.0_deg, -10.0_deg, 0.0_deg, 10.0_deg, 20.0_deg};
```

Of course, you can also add another operator function taking `int` as argument.

Comment: No, but I tried something similar and it seemed to solve the problem. You're right - GCC is not doing type conversion here

Answer (score 8):

Adding the definition

```
constexpr float operator "" _deg(unsigned long long d) {
    // returns radians
    return d*3.1415926535/180;
}
```

makes it work.

Comment: Yep, For numeric literals, the type of the cooked literal is either `unsigned long long` for integral literals or `long double` for floating point literals. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals)